# Comparing the List with Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
data1=[{'aa': None, 'bb': 'dffg', 'cc': '0', 'dd': '1234', 'ee': None}, 
{'aa': 'cdfg', 'bb': None, 'cc': '0', 'dd': 'sc12', 'ee': 'edft'},
{'aa': 'bvkjdi', 'bb': 'hdjd', 'cc': '0', 'dd': None, 'ee': None},
{'aa': None, 'bb': None, 'cc': '0', 'dd': '123dg', 'ee': 'hddk'}]


data2={'aa': ('','cdfg', 'bvkjdi', ''), 'bb': ('dffg','', 'hdjd', ''),
'cc': ('0', '0', '0','0'), 'dd': ('1234', 'sc12', '','123dg'),
'ee': ('', 'edft', '','hddk') }
```

data1 is list in that many dictionaries with its key values and data2 is dictionaries with its key values.Need to compare these two but the format is different.Need to figure out and easy way to compare 'aa' of data1 to 'aa' from data2 , 'bb' values of data1 to 'bb' values of data2 similarly for the remaining things.Please help me to compare this.

Comment: what do you mean by compare?, the difference, the shared, true/false check to see if they are they same...?

Comment: @azorius :To check that they are same or not

Comment: Please make an example. You do not need to show code, just show your "dict" and your "list" and the expected output.

Comment: It's easy to make something from `data1` which has the same structure as `data2`, but it's not obvious to me how you want to compare `None` and `''`, or `'0'` and `0`, which aren't equal in Python but I suspect you may want them to be treated as if they were.

Comment: @DSM : from data1 None == '' and from data2 '0' = '0', small mistake, wil edit it

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
>>> data1_like_data2 = {}
>>> for item in data1:
...     for key in item:
...         try:
...             data1_like_data2[key] += (item[key],)
...         except:
...             data1_like_data2.update({key:(item[key],)})
>>> data1_like_data2
{'aa': (None, 'cdfg', 'bvkjdi', None), 'cc': ('0', '0', '0', '0'), 'dd': ('1234', 'sc12', None, '123dg'), 'ee': (None, 'edft', None, 'hddk'), 'bb': ('dffg', None, 'hdjd', None)}
```

Then compare them directly,

```
>>> data1_like_data2 == data2:
>>> False
```

It's giving False because of None and '0' problem. Get that sorted according to your requirement, then it'll work.

Comment: @ Sudipta : I need to compare only aa and bb values of data1 to aa and bb values of data2, please help me

Answer (score 0):

assuming that None = '' and 0 = '0'
I think this what you want:

```
data1=[{'aa': None, 'bb': 'dffg', 'cc': 0, 'dd': '1234', 'ee': None}, 
{'aa': 'cdfg', 'bb': None, 'cc': 0, 'dd': 'sc12', 'ee': 'edft'},
{'aa': 'bvkjdi', 'bb': 'hdjd', 'cc': 0, 'dd': None, 'ee': None},
{'aa': None, 'bb': None, 'cc': 0, 'dd': '123dg', 'ee': 'hddk'}]


data2={'aa': ('','cdfg', 'bvkjdi', ''), 'bb': ('dffg','', 'hdjd', ''),
'cc': ('0', '0', '0','0'), 'dd': ('1234', 'sc12', '','123dg'),
'ee': ('', 'edft', '','hddk') }

results = {}
for key in data2:
    set1 = [x[key] for x in data1]
    set1 = [str(x) if x is not None else '' for x in set1]
    set2 = list(data2[key])

    results[key] = set1 == set2        
# results = {'aa': True, 'cc': True, 'dd': True, 'ee': True, 'bb': True}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure `data1` to look like `data2` using a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> n = {k: tuple(d[k] for d in data1) for k in data2}
>>> n
{'aa': (None, 'cdfg', 'bvkjdi', None), 'cc': ('0', '0', '0', '0'), 
'dd': ('1234', 'sc12', None, '123dg'), 'ee': (None, 'edft', None, 'hddk'), 
'bb': ('dffg', None, 'hdjd', None)}
```

Since you want `None` to match `''`, we can convert those too:

```
>>> n = {k: tuple(d[k] if d[k] is not None else '' for d in data1) for k in data2}
>>> n
{'aa': ('', 'cdfg', 'bvkjdi', ''), 'cc': ('0', '0', '0', '0'), 
'dd': ('1234', 'sc12', '', '123dg'), 'ee': ('', 'edft', '', 'hddk'), 
'bb': ('dffg', '', 'hdjd', '')}
```

After which:

```
>>> n == data2
True
```

If you only want to compare the `aa` and `bb` key/value pairs, you could pull them out:

```
>>> keys_to_compare = {'aa', 'bb'}
>>> d1 = {k: tuple(d[k] if d[k] is not None else '' for d in data1) for k in keys_to_compare}
>>> d2 = {k: v for k,v in data2.iteritems() if k in keys_to_compare}
>>> d1 == d2
True
```

Or compare them in-place:

```
>>> all(tuple(d[k] if d[k] is not None else '' for d in data1) == data2[k] for k in keys_to_compare)
True
```

Comment: I need to compare only aa and bb values of data1 to aa and bb values of data2, please help me.

Comment: @user2558589: didn't you say "similarly for the remaining things"?